# Terraform: can I pass ignore_changes to the module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

Can I pass `ignore_changes` to the terraform module?
In my case, I do not want to update the autoscaling group, when AMI was updated.

After a brief review, it seems that it cannot be done - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21546

Of course, I can have two copy-pasted module versions - one with `ignore_changes` and another without, but it doesn't look good. Maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 8):

As of 2-16-2022, it seems this isn't possible. There are two issues documenting this on GitHub, one as you pointed out [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21546) and another more generic issue about handling interpolation in lifecycle attributes at: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3116 . As of now, the reasoning seems to be:

> @phinze:
> The real issue here is that lifecycle blocks cannot contain interpolated values. This is because lifecycle modifications can change the shape of the graph, which makes handling computed values for them extra tricky. It's something we can theoretically do, but requires some thought and effort. Tagging as an enhancement.

---

For a workaround (albeit not optimal), we can hardcode the values into `ignore_changes` on the module scope and then use `count` with a variable e.g. `create_resource_with_ignore_changes = 1` to get our resource provisioned with `ignore_changes` from the module scope. I know this isn't what the question requested, instead this is hardcoding `ignore_changes` into the module and provisioning it via a count switch. Below is an example of how this could work:

**variables.tf**

```
variable "create_resource_with_ignore_changes" {
  type        = number
  description = "Choose whether to create a version that uses hardcoded ignore_changes"
  default     = 1
}
```

**calling-a-module.tf**

```
module "servers" {
  source                              = "./app-cluster"
  create_resource_with_ignore_changes = var.create_resource_with_ignore_changes
}
```

**inside-servers-module.tf**

```
resource "a_terraform_resource" "example" {
  count = var.create_resource_with_ignore_changes
  # ...
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        # your hardcoded changes to ignore here
    ]
  }
}
```

---

A benefit of this approach is that you can have different configurations by still using a single module. You can also nest other logic into the count argument, for instance, via creating a string and determining if it matches using a ternary operator:

```
resource "a_terraform_resource" "example" {
  count = var.my_resource_config == "someHardcodedNamedConfig" ? 1 : 0
  # ...
}
```

---

This also got me thinking if it's possible just to conditionally control the `lifecycle` block. There's a SO post which answers that question here: [Terraform conditionally apply lifecycle block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427931/terraform-conditionally-apply-lifecycle-block)

Unfortunately this also isn't possible, for similar reasons to the explanation to this particular question, making the duplicate resource (one with and one without the `lifecycle` block) the current feasible workaround.