# Terraform keeps removing virtual_network_subnet_id and in a subsequent run re-adding the vnet integration for an azurerm_linux_function_app

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure, subnet, vnet

I've created a terraform script with an azurerm_linux_function_app with vnet integration (using azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection). If I run the Terraform script everything works as expected, but if I run Terraform again it proposes to update the function app in-place by removing the virtual_network_subnet_id, which then breaks the vnet integration. If I run terraform again it proposes to create azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection again and everything works and this loop continues.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  name                 = "name"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.5.128/26"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"]
  delegation {
    name = "name-delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "this" {
  name                       = "name"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.this.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.this.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.this.id
  https_only                 = true
  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true
    cors {
      allowed_origins = ["https://portal.azure.com"]
    }
    application_stack {
      node_version = "18"
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "this" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.this.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.this.id
}
```

Comment: The `plan` outputs' snippets would be relevant here too.

Comment: Problem was solved by adding virtual_network_subnet_id  = azurerm_subnet.this.id to the linux function app directly and by removing the swift connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Glad the problem was solved As a workaround instead of removing swift connection***

***You can make use of lifecycle block as mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856640/terraform-lifecycle-ignore-changes) in your terraform code to avoid your swift connection from updating again***, Refer below:-

**My Terraform code:-**

> **I have referred the below terraform code from this [**Official  Terraform document**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection)  and modified the code by adding Depends on and lifecycle block.**

```
# We strongly recommend using the required_providers block to set the
# Azure Provider source and version being used
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.58.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "subid"
tenant_id = "tenantid"
client_id = "clientid"
client_secret = "clientsecret"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-virtual-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  

  delegation {
    name = "example-delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "siliconstrg54332"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "siliconfunc-0987"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_plan.example]
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "this" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_function_app.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id

depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.example, azurerm_function_app.example]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

**lifecycle block:-**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "this" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_function_app.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id

depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.example, azurerm_function_app.example]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

When I ran the Plan again it did not ask me to update Swift connection or Function app except for asking me to add the tag as cost center refer below:-

[image]

You can add the tags by adding this

```
tags = { costCenter = "My Cost Center" }
```

in your resource block after tadding this in my resource block when I ran the plan I got the desired state refer below:-

[image]

> **Complete code with tag referred from this [Official Terraform Document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection) modified with Depends on and lifecycle block.**

```
# We strongly recommend using the required_providers block to set the
# Azure Provider source and version being used
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.58.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "subid"
tenant_id = "tenantid"
client_id = "clientid"
client_secret = "clientsecret"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-virtual-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tags = {
    costCenter = "My Cost Center"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  

  delegation {
    name = "example-delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
  tags = {
    costCenter = "My Cost Center"
}
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "siliconstrg54332"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  
  tags = {
    costCenter = "My Cost Center"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "siliconfunc-0987"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  tags = {
    costCenter = "My Cost Center"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_plan.example]
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "this" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_function_app.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id

depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.example, azurerm_function_app.example]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for windows functions. It still removes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong. Indeed, the following code provisions the VNET integration with the function app.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "this" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_function_app.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
}
```

However, it is not on that very same resource that changes to `subnet_id` should be ignored. It is on the `azurerm_function_app` resource that the following should be added, thus ignoring changes to the VNET integration with the function app:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [virtual_network_subnet_id]
  }
```